# make one arrays content into another 2d arrays rows & colums

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have this function that reads a textfile and sends the strings to an array and then from that function I send that array and number of elements to my constructor. Now my constructor creates a dynamic 2d-array(I hope). I would like my 2d-arrays rows and columns to be assigned values from the array received.

heres my constructor.

```
Graph::Graph(string cities[], int n)
{
     this->nrOfCities=n;
     this->x=n;
     this->y=n;
     this->graph=new string *[x];
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
        this->graph[i] =new string[y];
     for(int i=0;i<this->x;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<this->x;j++)
           this->graph[j]=NULL;
     for(int i=0;i<=this->x;i++)//I know this last part doesn't work.
         for(int j=0;j<this->x;j++)
             this->graph[0][j+1]=cities[j];
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What is second outer for doing? If you're not using i? Also third outer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a dynamic 2darray you must try s.th. like this:

```
type** arr2d;
arr2d = new type*[rows];
for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
  arr2d[i] = new type[cols];
```

Comment: 2darr is not a valid name for a variable in C++ since it starts with a number.

Comment: do you mean something like this?

`this->graph=new string[x];
 for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
this->graph[i] = new string[y];`
this wont work for me, complains about the assignment operator.

Comment: @ogward What does it exactly say?

Comment: it says `a value of type "std::string *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "std::string **"`

Comment: @ogward: `graph` must be of type `string**`. Is it? I edited answer so it shows type of `arr2d`.